# finding strings in a log file with re

Tags: python, regex

Line in log file i would search for information

```
bkup = "2015-03-27 09:54 *** Backup done.  Errors: 0.  Processed files: 8748.    Backed up files: 8748. Total size: 5.80 GB ***"
```

Code i would use to pull info

```
end = re.findall(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\*\*\*\sBackup\sdone\.\s\sErrors:\s\d{1,5}\.\s\sProcessed\sfiles:\s\d{1,5}\.\sBacked\sup\sfiles:\s\d{1,5}\.\sTotal\ssize:\s\d{1,5}\.\d{1,2}\d{1,2}\s[M|G]B\s\*\*\*', bkup)
```

This works perfect for when the "Total size:" is quoted as MB or GB but not when it reads "bytes"

e.g.

```
bkup = "2015-03-27 09:54 *** Backup done.  Errors: 0.  Processed files: 8748. Backed up files: 8748. Total size: 0 bytes ***"
```

Is there a way to find MB or GB or bytes.
I am not a pro at Python yet so don't chew me up. This is my first question here.

Comment: How about you learn about regular expressions? [M|G] is surely not what you want. That describes a set of 3 characters ('M', '|', and 'G').

Comment: Am learning. As i said am no pro yet. The purpose of a question base site is not to respond with "How about you learn about....etc." we all are at different levels.

Comment: Sure. But to use regular expressions you need to be at a different level. And to get there you need to learn regular languages, finite state machines etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:[GM]B|bytes?)","2015-03-27 09:54 *** Backup done.  Errors: 0.  Processed files: 8748.    Backed up files: 8748. Total size: 5.80 GB *** 5.80 MB 612323 bytes   612323 byte",re.I)
```

You can directly use this .[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/2)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this in your expression:
`(MB|GB|bytes)`
It will match 'MB' or 'GB' or 'bytes'.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = re.compile(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\*\*\*\sBackup\sdone\.\s\sErrors:\s\d{1,5}\.\s\sProcessed\sfiles:\s\d{1,5}\.\sBacked\sup\sfiles:\s\d{1,5}\.\sTotal\ssize:\s\d+(\.\d+)?\s(MB|GB|bytes)\s\*\*\*')
if m.match(bkup):
    # do something
    pass
```

\d+(.\d+)? match 5.80 or 0

(MB|GB|bytes) match MB or GB or bytes